# create GET request from text box action

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

When a user enters text or clicks go, I need to redirect them to a page with the value they entered as a GET request. I can't figure this out for the life of me.

I'm using bootstrap and currently have:

```
        <div class="input-group">
           <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="channel name here...">
           <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Go!</button>
           </span>
        </div>
```

which produces:
[image]
When a user enters text and clicks go, or hits enter I want to redirect them to

example.com/search/?text=TEXT_ENTERED

Comment: [The HTML5 placeholder attribute is not a substitute for the label element](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201204/the_html5_placeholder_attribute_is_not_a_substitute_for_the_label_element/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Replace the div with a `form`.
- Set the `action` of the form to the URL (sans query string) you want to go to.
- Give the `input` a `name` (`text` in your example)
- Remove the `type` attribute from the `button` to make it a submit button

… and forget about JavaScript. It isn't needed for this.

Comment: @user3204017 I added a plunkr with the suggestions from @Quentin http://run.plnkr.co/HONCnKGvQJuzsPbd/ (Note -- when submitting the form an error appear because there is no /search/ on the server. But you will se that the URL now is what you want: `/search/?text=foobar`

Answer (score -1):

This requires a simple application of the `<form>` HTML element. Simply surround your `<input>` with something like this:

```
<!-- Replace "/search" with the location of your search page -->
<form action="/search" method="GET">
    <!-- Your search field -->
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="channel name here...">
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <!-- Make sure this is a submit button, like @Quentin mentioned -->
            <button class="btn btn-default">Go!</button>
        </span>
    </div>
</form>
```

Now, pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> on your search field or clicking "Go!" will yield the same result, and you should arrive the desired URL: `mysite.com/search/?text=TEXT_ENTERED`

Happy coding!

Answer (score -1):

You could use forms or if you want to redirect, you could just add an event handler to the click event that sets window.location to http://example.com/search/?text=TEXT_ENTERED.  Or you could just make an AJAX request using some JavaScript library like jQuery.

```
<button id="myButton" class="btn btn-default" type="button">Go!</button>
$("#myButton").on("click", function () {
$.ajax({
            url: 'http://example.com/search/?text=' + $("#myButton").text(),
            error: function (err) {
                    console.warn("Error", err);
                }
            },
            success: function (response) {
              //handle success
            },
            type: 'get'
        });
}
```